# Error occurs only when initializing more than 1 datatable on a page

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to have 2 datatables on one page.

I'm not initializing them in one function call, however.

I'm initializing them in separate function calls.

I've made a javascript function that looks like this:

```
function initialize_datatable(args) {
    generate_footer(args.table_selector);
    $(args.table_selector).DataTable({
        columns: args.columns,
        order: args.order,
        scrollX: true,
        ...
        ...
```

Is it not possible to call this method twice?

Do I need to consolidate multiple tables into one `.DataTable()` initialization? E.g. `$('#table-one #table-two #table-three').DataTable()`?

Whenever I try to make two separate calls to `.DataTable()` I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined`. If you Google this error it says this error occurs because you have a differing number of  elements in your header and footer. I have counted my `<th>` elements in my header footer, they are the same number.

I can initialize one table, or the other, but not both at the same time, so I know it's an issue with making multiple calls to `.DataTable()`

This is the full definition of `initialize_datatable`:

```
function initialize_datatable(args) {
    generate_footer(args.table_selector);
    $(args.table_selector).DataTable({
        columns: args.columns,
        order: args.order,
        scrollX: true,
        sScrollXInner: "100%",
        dom: "Blfrtip",
        buttons: [
            {
                extend       : 'copyHtml5',
                title        : args.title,
                sheetName    : args.title,
                footer       : true,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend       : 'excelHtml5',
                footer       : true,
                title        : args.title,
                sheetName    : args.title,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend       : 'csvHtml5',
                title        : args.title,
                sheetName    : args.title,
                footer       : true,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend       : 'print',
                text         : 'Print',
                title        : args.title,
                sheetName    : args.title,
                autoPrint    : true,
                footer       : true,
                stripHtml    : false,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',
                }
            }
        ],
        drawCallback: function () {
            let api = this.api();

            // hide columns that add up to 0
            api.columns().every(function (i) {
                let sum = this.data().sum();
                if (sum === 0 && typeof sum === 'number' && i !== 0) {
                    api.column(i).visible(0);
                }
            });
        }, 
        footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            let api = this.api()

            intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            }

            api.columns({page: 'current'}).every(function (i) {
                let columnTotal = this.data().reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

                if (!isNaN(columnTotal)) {
                    columnTotal = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).format(columnTotal);
                    $(this.footer()).html(columnTotal);
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Should there be a language tag? [tag:JavaScript] (and [tag:jQuery] too)